# Correct compilaton and linking flags for building python c/c++ extension on Windows, linux and OSX

Tags: python

Environment:

```
Python 3.8.10
Windows 10
Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64)
Msys2 (Mingw64)
```

This post is about getting the correct set of compilation and linking flags as well as set of libraries for building Python extensions using c/c++ on three major OS.

**MS Windows Mingw64**

The command

```
python -m sysconfig
```

gives you a very small set of flags compared to Linux and no information is available for compilation and linking flags. I'm using the Mingw64 compiler toolchain on Windows which I believe is not officially supported on Windows. After following everything that was once required to build extension using MinGW on Windows I was still not able to get it correctly done.

For e.g cython is using gcc for compilation and g++ for linking and adding msvc flags while linking.
After doing things manually, I came up with these flags:

```
Compilation C/C++: '-c', '-Ofast', '-fpic', '-mdll', '-Wall'
Linking: '-shared' '-O', '-Wall'
Macros: "-DMS_WIN64"
Includes: "from sysconfig import get_paths as gp; gp()["include"]"
Libraries: "-lPythonXX"
```

**MS Windows MSVC**

I'm not using MSVC as of now but I would switch to it soon. I would really appreciate if someone could post the required flags.
for MSVC.

**Linux**

On Linux you have two options:

```
python3 -m sysconfig
&
python-config --cflags
python-config --ldflags
```

and I came up with these flags:

```
Compilation C/C++ : "-Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2"
Linking : "-shared -fPIC -Wl, -O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -g -fwrapv -O2"
Macros: ""
Includes: "from sysconfig import get_paths as gp; gp()["include"]"
Libraries: "-lcrypt -ldl  -lm -lm -lPythonXX"
```

**OSX**

I don't have access to Apple Mac OSX but I believe flags would be the same as of Linux. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Prashant